# How to make div draggable by an image inside

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-draggable

I have a div  and I am trying to drag it by a image inside the div.
Below is my html

```
  <div id="MainDiv">
  <img src="Images/Drag.png"/>

<div>Test</div><div>Tes2</div>
</div>
```

I have made the main div draggable but I want to drag with the help of image drag.png which is inside the maindiv.
How to achieve this .Please help me on this..

Comment: Change your selector, which I'm guessing is $("MainDiv") to $("MainDiv img"). And add further code to show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `handle`-option of the draggable-function:

```
$( "#MainDiv" ).draggable({
    handle: "img"
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ntk0Ls27/)

**Reference**

[draggable - handle](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-handle)

Comment: I tried with below but is not working for me

$("#MainDiv").draggable({
        cursor: "move",
          handle: "img",        
        addClasses: false,
        axis: "x y",
        appendTo: "body",
        snap: true,
        revert: 'invalid',
        start: function () {
            $(this).data("origPosition", $(this).position());
        }
    });

Comment: @sandeep.mishra What is not working and what do you expect to happen ? see the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kn8zjp0L/)

Comment: Sorry empiric. Its working .Thanks a lot. I was trying with the droppable then draggable .
Now its working when I reversed the order.

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d58JF/12/)

with jquery events 
`$('#movable').on('mousedown',)` possible without jquery UI also